# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'iterrows'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, series, attributeerror

```py
accounts = pd.read_csv('C:/*******/New_export.txt', sep=",", dtype={'number': object})
accounts.columns = ["Number", "F"]

for i, j in accounts["Number"].iterrows(): #i represents the row(index number), j is the number
    if (str(j) == "27*******5"):
        print(accounts["F"][i], accounts["Number"][i])
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'iterrows'
```

I don't quite understand the error since "accounts" is a pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`accounts["Number"]` is a *Series* object, not a DataFrame. Either iterate over `accounts.iterrows()` and take the `Number` column from each row, or use the [`Series.items()` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.items.html).

Iterating over the dataframe:

```
for i, row in accounts.iterrows():
    if str(row['Number']) == "27*******5":
        print(row["F"], row["Number"])
```

or over `Series.items()`:

```
for i, number in accounts['Number'].items():
    if str(number) == "27*******5":
        print(accounts["F"][i], number)
```

Answer (score 1):

To iterate over a dataframe column (such as `accounts['Number']`) or a pandas Series, use `items()`, which creates a `zip` object.

```py
for i, j in accounts["Number"].items():
#                             ^^^^^^^^^
    if (str(j) == "27*******5"):
        print(accounts["F"][i], accounts["Number"][i])
```

That said, iterating over a column is rarely needed as there are faster ways to filter a column. For example, for the case in the OP, filtering using a boolean mask instead of the if-clause produces the same thing:

```py
print(accounts.loc[accounts["Number"].map(str) == "27*******5", ['F', 'Number']])
```