# How to get index names in Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I need to get the index name from my DataFrame when I use a for loop.

My DataFrame looks like this:

```
+---------+------+
| Country | Code |
+---------+------+
| ABW     |  944 |
| AFG     |  761 |
| AGO     |  586 |
+---------+------+
```

I've tried this code:

```py
for index, nb_indicateurs in explore['2010'].iterrows():
    print(index)
```

But it gives this error:

> 'Series' object has no attribute 'iterrows'

Can someone help me??

Comment: Do you mean df.index?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54991052/11035198

Comment: thank you  i try the solution of the post it's working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'iterrows'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54991008/attributeerror-series-object-has-no-attribute-iterrows)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the datatype of explore['2010'] is Series. In that case, 'Country' is already the index. Try:

```
print(explore['2010'].index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a series format, I think it should be used in a data frame format.

```
for index ,nb_indicateurs in explore[['2010']].iterrows():
    print(index)
```